# Не записываются данные в БД с применением jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не записываются данные с формы в БД? Вот код js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // When user clicks on submit comment to add comment under post
  $('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var user_id = $('.userid').val();
    var username = $('.username').val();
    var message = $('.message').val();    
    var url = $('.comment_form').attr('action');

   e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "username": username,
        "message": message
      },
      cache: false,      
      success: function(data){

          $('.username').val('');
          $('.message').val('');
          $('.show').prepend('<p>' + username + '</p><p>' + message + '</p>');

        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Код PHP (send.php)

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
require 'rb.php';

 R::setup('mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=ajax_test', 'root', '');

 if (!R::testConnection()) 
 {
    exit('Не удалось соединиться с базой данных!');
 }
R::freeze(true);
$data = $_POST;
if (isset($data['submit_data'])) {
    $user_id = $data['user_id'];
    $user_name = $data['username'];
    $message = $data['message'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $errors = array();


    if (empty($data['username']) || empty($data['message']) ) {
        $errors[] = 'No Value entered';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $messages = R::dispense('messages');
        $messages->user_id = $user_id;
        $messages->username = $user_name;
        $messages->message = $message;
        $messages->ip = $ip;
        $messages->pubdate = date('d.m.Y H:i');
        R::store($messages);
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    }else {
  $errors =  array_shift($errors);    
}
}
?>
```

И код формы index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Учим Javascript</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  

<form class="comment_form" action="send.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="userid" value="5">
<input type="text" name="username" class="username"><br>
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" class="message"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit_data" class="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div class="show"></div>


<noscript>JAVASCRIPT IS NOT WORKING ON YOUR BROWSER</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что в **консоле** и **Network**?

Comment: а на каком моменте ошибка? данные приходят на сервер? на  сервере обрабатываются? попробуйте обернуть `data` в `json.stringify`. А в общем нужно больше информации

Comment: Прошу прощения, я e.preventDefault закомментировал. Точнее = без preventDefault записываются данные в БД, но страница обновляется.

Comment: @Хруст чтобы страница не обновлялась замените `<input type="submit" ... >` на `<input type="button" ... >`

Comment: А если же я использую preventDefault, то в бд данные формы не записываются

Comment: @Хруст по поводу `e.preventDefault();` - смотрите консоль, проблемы описанной Вами быть не должно.

Comment: Нет, все так же. Убираю e.preventDefault(); -данные записываются в БД, но происходит перезагрузка страницы. А с ней - не записывается.

Comment: И в консоли, и в network ошибки не выходят

Comment: @Хруст вот зачем Вы нас обманываете? Перезагрузки не будет: **[1. вариант с input button](https://jsfiddle.net/v1nb3L9z/)**, **[2. вариант с e.preventDefault()](https://jsfiddle.net/v1nb3L9z/1/)**. В обоих случаях данные уходят на сервер, перезагрузки не происходит.

Comment: @Хруст смотрим дальше: `if (isset($data['submit_data'])){....}` - где в ajax Вы отправляете `submit_data` ? правильно, нигде. Поэтому после `$data = $_POST;` ничему выполняться.

Comment: Тогда значит у меня проблемы с сервером или еще где... А по поводу "if (isset($data['submit_data'])){....} - где в ajax Вы отправляете submit_data ? правильно, нигде" не могли бы вы подсказать, чего надо сделать?

Comment: @Хруст после `"message": message` добавьте запятую и ниже строку `"submit_data": $(".submit").val()`

Comment: Нет, БД пустая...

Comment: @Alex, большое вам спасибо, все получилось!

Comment: @Хруст пожалуйста. ответ нужно публиковать или удалите вопрос ?

Comment: Нет, удалять не буду, вдруг кому понадобиться.

Comment: *понадобится...

Comment: @Хруст ответ опубликован. Для того, чтобы [отметить ответ принятым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ [отмечен как решение вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема в том, что на серверной стороне (*send.php*) Вы делаете проверку:

```
$data = $_POST;
if (isset($data['submit_data'])) {
  ...
}
```

при этом в *ajax* Вы не передаете `submit_data`, следовательно на серверной стороне(*send.php*) после `$data = $_POST;` выполняться нечему, поэтому данные не записываются.

Вам необходимо добавить `submit_data` в запрос ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    "user_id": user_id,
    "username": username,
    "message": message,
    "submit_data": $(".submit").val()
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    $('.username').val('');
    $('.message').val('');
    $('.show').prepend('<p>' + username + '</p><p>' + message + '</p>');
  }
});
```

---

как еще можно проверить на серверной стороне, что поступили данные, переданные методом *POST*:

- `if($_POST) { ... }`
- `if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ... }`
- `if(count($_POST) > 0) { ... }`

Comment: Добрый вечер!
Опять вопрос
Json_encode. в этих же скриптах

Comment: @Хруст здравствуйте. в данном вопросе нет упоминания о json_encode. Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста создайте новый вопрос.